# How can I add a new step to the CheckOut in Prestashop v1.7?

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty, checkout, prestashop-1.7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqMt1.png)

Hi guys,

I need some help and tricks for develop the next requirement;

I am using the Prestashop version 1.7.2.4; I need to add a new step between the LOGIN STEP and THE ADDRESS STEP.

For example in this NEW STEP I want to add a dropdown or select2 or combobox to show for examples the cities of my country and with the select value feed the next step.

Some suggestions or tricks are welcome !

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I am developing a new step. I used the code above, but that's just the beginning. I was guided by the management processes and personal information.

- check controllers/front/OrderController.php

#### Code

```
$this->checkoutProcess
        ->addStep(new CheckoutPaymentStep(
            $this->context,
            $translator,
            new PaymentOptionsFinder(),
            new ConditionsToApproveFinder(
                $this->context,
                $translator
            )
        ))
    ;
```

that is the beginning there is more, guiate of the other processes are there, copy and paste one below, edit taking in reference the other steps. I'm doing it, but I have problems with relationships.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why not populating it on first or second step if it's just a selector ?

An idea could be to hide address selection and feeding it after with some Javascript.

Anyway you could use a hook and a module to implement it with a better compliance to Prestashop's model.

You can find module/hook generator here : http://validator.prestashop.com
And a list of hooks here with their usage : http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS17/Hooks+in+PrestaShop+1.7.x